# How to get url parameter from current route in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a route like this:

```
http://localhost/c/61/legetoj
```

its defined as:

```
 routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Category",
                        "c/{categoryId}/{SeName}",
                        new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
                        new { categoryId = @"\d+" },
                        new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

Now, on all the pages having this url, I want to get SeName value (here is `legetoj')

In my **view** (header) I've tried this with: `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["SeName"]`
but it returns empty..

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up an action with the same name parameter as you would like to accept such as:

```
public ActionResult Category(int categoryId, string SeName) {
// do stuff
}
```

It should automatically insert that value inside the variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I need this parameter in the view to pass to another @Html.Action

Comment: @CristianBoariu - So pass it to the view from your controller.  That's the correct way to do it.

Comment: To be more explicit: I don't need it in the Category View but in my header...so my header already accepts another model that's why I don't want to mix the things here...